# Using variables in node.js mySQL query

Tags: mysql, node.js, string, concatenation, connection-string

In my node application I recieve data through a form. Then I want to store it in a mySQL database with the help of the mysql package. The data is validated and sanitized to ensure expected values are passed to the database.

When sending a query to the mySQL server, I recieve an **ER_PARSE_ERROR:**
- *You have an error in your SQL syntax; [...] 'insert into 'reservierung' (null, 'testName', ''*

Weird since the same approach worked when using the workbench.

```
let queryInput = `insert into reservierung
                  values(null, '${resVorName}', '${resNachName}', '${resEmail}', '${tischVal}', 0);
                 `;
```

I already tried concatenating the variables with the + operator instead of using ${variable} but that did not resolve the issue. I also tried wrapping the variables inside **'%'** because I read that a single quote might be escaped, but that did not help either.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

try using this syntax :

```
    INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
           VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
let values = [resVorName,resNachName,resEmail];


let queryInput = 'INSERT INTO myTable (field1, field2, field3) VALUES ?', [values])
```